# Exe - Embed JRE to a Standalone EXE?

Tags: java, inno-setup

I want to ask if there's a way on how I can embed the jre bundle folder to my EXE App using Inno Setup? I just want to create an installer for my standalone application but my functions is not working if there's no jre installed on other pc

Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Wow, that's what I'm looking for! Super Thanks!